# Why ODE solver in MATLAB pop out out of memory, even the matrix is not large?

Tags: matlab, solver, ode

I try to solve a simulation problem based on ODE. 
But I get out of memory problem, could someone help me on this, a little bit hint?

***Warning: Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled. Results may be***

inaccurate. RCOND =  1.453788e-16. 
  In ode23s at 207
  In tr_ode at 77

Warning: Matrix is singular to working precision. 
  In ode23s at 207
  In tr_ode at 77

***Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.***

Error in odenumjac (line 127)
  ydel = y(:,ones(1,ny)) + diag(del);

Error in ode23s (line 224)
  [dfdy,Joptions.fac,nF] = odenumjac(odeFcn, {t,y,odeArgs{:}}, f0, Joptions);

Error in tr_pdn_ode_matlab_v (line 77)
[t,x] = ode23s(@f, [0,sim_param.end_time ], voltage, options);

The matrix is sparse and only 45784*45784

My machine is 64 bit and 12GB memory. MATLAB 2012b.

code snapshot:

```
...
options  = odeset('Mass', M); % M is a sparse matrix
[t,x] = ode45(@f, [0,end_time ], v, options); 
% end_time = 10^-8 , v is init. condition for f. 
... 
function out = f( t , y)
    out = -Gl *y ; % Gl is a sparse matrix
end
```

Comment: How do you call `ode23s`? How do you call `odeset`? Please show your code. A [minimal, complete, tested and readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help a lot and avoid confusion.

Comment: Your error mentions `ode23` yet you just posted code for `ode45`. Are you sure that gives the same thing? You give no values for `M`, `end_time`, `v`, etc. so I can't run this without a lot of work on my end.

Comment: In fact, I cannot replicate your error. Please provide code that is runnable, that actually produces the error, and that is consistent with the rest of your question

Comment: oh, my matrix is too large to show here actually, and loaded using a mat. I thought you want to check the usage of ode solver. Or I can send you via other way if you want.

Comment: No one wants to see your actual matrix. You must be able to create small runnable example code that generates a sparse matrix itself and replicates the issue so we can see What functions you're calling and try it ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't a small matrix. If stored non-sparsely, it would be 16GB. ODENUMJAC should be implemented in such a way not to destroy your sparse storage, but it might be that some little bug somewhere tries to store it in full format. It might also be that it's stored right but just a lot bigger than you realize.

Comment: hi, mike, thanks. it is very sparse, and stored as sparse structure, and then put into ode solver, both ode23s, and ode15s. You means the internal matlab code may have bug for such scenario? FYI, It can be solved by my hand code trapezoidal method too.